# Is there a list of ordered Broadcast receiver's list?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, abortbroadcast

Is there a way in Android to determine which `BroadcastReceivers` are ordered ones? I was testing the `abortBroadcast()` function however, none of the broadcast receivers that I tested were ordered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There aren't many. This isn't an exhaustive list, but here are a few examples:

```
android.intent.action.DATA_SMS_RECEIVED
android.provider.Telephony.SMS_CB_RECEIVED
android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED
android.intent.action.CAMERA_BUTTON
android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON
android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF
android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON
android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL (you aren't allowed to abort this)
```

If you just want to test the behaviour, you can create your own broadcast `Intent` and register some receivers and then send an ordered broadcast.